# Biding dictionary key values to listbox and removing thereafter

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, dictionary, listbox

I am trying to bind keys from a `dictionary` to a `listbox`. I also want to create  a button that allows me to remove an item from the `listbox` and `dictionary`.

**Edit:**

I've used the following code for binding the `dictionary` to the `listbox`:

```
listbox.DataSource = new BindingSource(dictionary, nothing)
listbox.DisplayMember = "Value"
listbox.ValueMember = "Key"
```

However when  I try to remove a selected item from the listbox with the following code:

```
listbox.Items.Remove(listbox.SelectedItem)
```

I get an error saying "item collection cannot be modified when DataSource property is set." How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for

```
lb.Items.AddRange(dict.Keys.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're binding the datasource, wouldn't you remove the item from the dictionary instead of the List Box?

```
Dict.Remove(listbox.SelectedValue)
```

That should remove from the list box as well since they are bound together